# Sidebar height not 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I am using [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/admin-side-menu) example and copied the same exact code but for some reason my page has a gap between the top of the page and the sidebar as shown in the picture.

I tied absolute and fixed positioning. The height in css is already set to 100%.

What do I need to do to close that gap ?

[image]

Comment: You should post minimal code that you have. HTML and CSS. I can't help you only with an image.

Comment: Have you checked whether the body or any other tags outside your example contain any kind of padding?

Comment: You removed bootstrap navbar but not removed margin-top from body?

Comment: Second that, if you aren't using a reset stylesheet some elements may have padding/margin that were added by default

Comment: Ah yes thats probably the issue so silly of me

Comment: well.. devtools seems to be the obvious solution, use it if you haven't yet done that, check each element, try to figure out what causes that gap, it seems to be some margin or padding at the first glance though.

Comment: Yes, there was `padding-top: 50px;` Apologies for wasting your time for such a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the actual html/css it's hard to guess what the problem is, however from the small strip of bookmarks in your screenshot it looks like you are using Chrome browser which will allow you to "Right Click -> Inspect Element" on the sidebar.

This will let you adjust the css properties live in the browser, from here if you click on the "Computed" tab you will be able to see all the CSS properties that are affecting the div.

I would recommend looking at the margin, padding and top property of the div.